# Making my app available only to my customer

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and I want it to be available only to my customer. No third party should be able to use it.

I need to authenticate it for this purpose. Currently I am using IMEI Number for device authentication by listing IMEI Numbers of the customer devices in the server but it is not working.

Is there any other way of authenticating my app to be used on customer devices only

Comment: Why don't you create credentials like username and password for your customers?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by available. If you're wanting to limit who can download and install the app, and if you are planning to distribute using the play store. you could setup a closed beta program adding only the emails you choose. That way only certain users can download and install. If you're wanting to limit availability for who can use the app once installed, a database is probably the way to go.

You could also hardcode the credentials if the rate at which they should change is low enough that you could just adjust it by releasing a new version.

Comment: It means I give 50 devices to my customer. The app should be able to run only on these 50 devices. Even if customer gives the newest(51st) to third party, it should not be able to run